# HBase IO concurrency issue, what if we scan hbase and put something matches scan condition at the same time?

Tags: hbase

OK, I want to test this scenario, but concurrency things, it's not easy to reproduce the issue even if there is.

Let's break it down:

```
Timeline:                         --------------------------------
Scan start and finish time:           |                      |
Scan cursor location:                             ^
Put operation took place:          a  b     c     d      e   f  g
```

- `a` put took place before scan even started, this one should be fount by scan
- `b` put took place at the same time of scan started, this one can be found?
- `c` put took place after scan started, but before scan cursor reached there
- `d` put took place just when scan cursor reached `d` as if it was already there
- `e` put took place after scan, I'm not sure about this one
- `f` put took place when scan just finished, this one definitely can not be found
- `g` can not found, no need to discuss

I want to know `b` `c` `d` `e` which are can be manipulated by scan operation, thanks.